# Get field from unstructured array in Prestodb

Tags: arraylist, presto, trino

Im trying to query a category and category id (cat_id), that are in an array, in presto db source as following.
I used a query "json_extract_scalar"(data.reason, '$[0].column') for other column and it worked, but it didnt works for these array, because this levels are unstructured, not in json, its in array format.
Anyone has some suggestion? I can't to catch the [catid], and I tried a lot solutions.

[image]

Comment: Could you please replace picture with plain text

Comment: Tks, worked here.

Answer (score 0):

It worked as following, using select and sailing between levels :

-- [data] is my array column

```
SELECT data[1][4]  as tester, 
data[1][4][2]   as tester4,
data[1][4][3]   as tester5  
from MyTable
```